# Unable to see queue information or messages in activemq webconsole

Tags: mysql, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to configure Activemq with MySql. Everything seems to have been configured properly as i am able to send and receive messages through code. But I'm not able to see any queue or messages information in the Activemq Web Console.

below is my activemq config . Any help is apprciated.

Thank you!

Activemq.xml:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
          <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
      </property>
  </bean>

  <broker useJmx="false" brokerName="jdbcBroker" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">

    <persistenceAdapter>  
     <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/activemq-data" dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>  
  </persistenceAdapter>
    <transportConnectors>
       <transportConnector name="default" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
    </transportConnectors>
  </broker>

  <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/activemq?relaxAutoCommit=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="admin"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="200"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
  </bean>

  <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the WebConsole is using JMX to retrieve data, you should try to remove useJmx="false" from your broker configuration.